# Wordpress CSS: Issue with wrapping text in news feed

Tags: html, css, wordpress

[image]

I am using wordpress 3.6 and the website link is [website link](http://www.kasperconsulting.com/)  The issue i am facing is that the text shown in the above image is getting truncated at the end.

I found that this section is controlled by the following plugin  jquery-vertical-scroller and when I looked at its css to control how the words are being formatted.

the entire css is given below :

```css
/*
Plugin Name: jQuery Vertical Scroller
Plugin URI: http://sirisgraphics.com/development/jquery-vertical-scroller-2-0
Description: A plugin to add a widget to scroll posts in your sidebar or footer widgets for WordPress powered by jQuery
Version: 2.3
Author: Vamsi Pulavarthi
Author URI: http://sirisgraphics.com/
License: GPLv2
*/

/* Widget related styles */
.sgjvs_widget_title {
    /* Add your custom css here  for title */
}
.sgjvs_widget_title a {
    /* Add your custom css here  for title */
    
}
.sgjvs_widget_date {
    /* Add your custom css here  for date */
}
.sgjvs_widget_content {
    /* Add your custom css here for content */
    font-style: italic !important;
    display: inline-block;
 word-wrap:break-word;  
}
.sgjvs_widget_excerpt {
    /* Add your custom css here for excerpt */
    font-style: italic !important;
}

/* Shortcode related styles */
.sgjvs_sc_title {
    /* Add your custom css here  for title */
}
.sgjvs_sc_title a {
    /* Add your custom css here  for title */
    
}
.sgjvs_sc_date {
    /* Add your custom css here  for date */
    
}
.sgjvs_sc_content {
    /* Add your custom css here for content */
    font-style: italic !important;
display: inline-block;
word-wrap:break-word; 
}
.sgjvs_sc_excerpt {
    /* Add your custom css here for excerpt */
    font-style: italic !important;
}
```

I tried making changes under the content section but its not working. 
Any help in this regards would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a size for class `.scrollingtext` . Just add this:

```
.scrollingtext{
   width: 100%;
}
```

Note: adjust at your needs

Comment: thanks that helped..will accept the answer in 2 minutes